# Calculating angle between the face of a pyramid and the base

Tags: trigonometry

I have the question "Calculate the angle between the face BCE and the base ABCD in the pyramid pictured below, giving your answer to 1 decimal place."

[image]

I assume the angle we are trying to find is B and so I draw a triangle DBE and use the cosine rule to get the answer of 74.6 degrees. However the answer should be 79 degrees.

Here is my working:

[image]

Is the angle B the correct angle which I need to find or is it a different angle ? Because I know the method to use but the angle B is giving an incorrect value so it can't be this.

Comment: take the midpoint of AD & BC, join these to E ...

Comment: The result of what you tried on your own is that you calculated the angle of the _edge_ $BE$ and the base $ABCD.$ There is not a convenient existing label that will correspond to the angle you need, so you have to do some construction/labeling of your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the midpoint of $AC$ be $M$ and the midpoint of $AD$ be $N$. Then $AC$ is perpendicular to $EM$. We can find the length of $NE$ using Pythagoras:

$NE = \sqrt{8^{2} - 1.5^{2}} =  \frac{\sqrt{247}}{2}$

Now we need to find $\angle ENM$

Again, since $ENM$ forms a right angled triangle, $\angle ENM = arccos(\frac{1.5}{\frac{\sqrt{247}}{2}}) = 78.9955... \approx 79$degrees

I can include a diagram if this is hard to follow.

Edit: diagram included:

[image]

Comment: Yes please could you include a diagram thanks for the help :)

Comment: Added the diagram

Comment: Can I just ask how you got to arccos(\frac{1.5}{\frac{\sqrt{247}}{2}}) like the steps before this using the full cosine rule ?  Thanks :)

Comment: This stems from the definition of 'cosine': the trigonometric function that is equal to the ratio of the side adjacent to an acute angle (in a right-angled triangle) to the hypotenuse.